# SWR Cache issues

Tags: reactjs, swr

Hi am getting a problem when i try to get the cache from the localStorage

This is my function like the swr docs

```
function localStorageProvider() {
  // When initializing, we restore the data from `localStorage` into a map.
  const map = new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app-cache') || '[]'))

  // Before unloading the app, we write back all the data into `localStorage`.
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    const appCache = JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.entries()))
    localStorage.setItem('app-cache', appCache)
  })

  // We still use the map for write & read for performance.
  return map
}
```

When i refresh the page i am getting the error of cannot read properties of undefined [0] .......

I already worked with swr cache before and didn't have any problems, maybe a version issue or something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the above provider function. Can you provide more info and code? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Same here. It seems like caching is still broken in SWR < 2.0 and React >= 18:
https://github.com/vercel/swr/issues/1904